# Who took care of Naruto when he was young?

Tags: naruto

In episode 350, we see that the Third Hokage took on to take care of Naruto. But towards the beginning of the anime Naruto is seen to be living alone.

Did Naruto live with the Third? If so, why did he leave there?

Comment: "take care of" and "live with"  is not the same...

Comment: @UwF Seems hard to take care of a baby without him living at your place.

Comment: Yeah, you figured it out, the old geezer even invented a new lactation jutsu  (人乳術) to physically take care of Naruto... :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Third Hokage promised Kushina, when she was dying, that he would take care of Naruto, and he did.

Whole villagers knew that a monster fox was inside Naruto. This news also spread to the other villages. If it weren't for the astute care of the Third Hokage, other villages would have kidnapped Naruto and would have absconded him out of Konoha.

The Third may not have sheltered him at home, but he did keep an eye for Naruto. That is what taking care means.

Besides, Iruka and others were there too. However, the main role was still played by the Third.

Comment: His Anbu guard mostly, and Minato`s private Anbu is a high probability. . .

Comment: Doesn't really explain his early years, e.g. 0-5. There was no Iruka until the Academy. A 1,2, or 3 years old cannot fend for itself, etc.

Comment: Its commonly held that Lord Sarutobi "oversaw" Naruto's general well-being the way a Principal "oversees" a school. Yes, he'd know/be closer to particular, gifted or special need students, but its _highly_ unlikely he'd see to the day-to-day teaching and care of a class; same thing with Sarutobi. As Hokage, making sure Naruto was provided for after previous Hokage's death would be a given. But there's _no clear data on **who did  the ACTUAL , daily, "hands-on:" RAISING of the kid?** Sarutobi was likely _too busy_ to do so himself, and was _already_ raising Konohamaru...but SOMEONE had to it

Comment: furthermore, as a newborn baby, let alone the orphan of the village champion, Naruto would have **needed** security and the same daily care **all newborn babies need.**  I can take  that ninja kids are highly self sufficient and can live alone by age 10....but from 0 to age 9, **who attended his daily needs?**  It's unlikely Naruto taught _himself_ how to walk, eat, potty train, write, etc, let alone do stuff like prepare food and prep for the academy. The kid wouldn't have even survived as a newborn, but there's not even mention of a _wet nurse!_ How did he make it to 10 with _no_ adult care?

Answer (score 4):

There is no canonical answer for this.

Naruto lived alone as a child.

As for who took care of him while he was a baby, no one knows.

The people that took care of him in his childhood were people like the Sandaime, Iruka, and the ramen guy. However, they did not fulfill the roles of parents. The closest person Naruto had as a parent was Jiraiya.

Comment: That makes little sense, though. Think of it this way; we know Gaara, who essentially had the same start as Naruto, save for the fact that his father was alive, _at least_ had elder siblings and his mom's brother to watch out for him when he was little. It's _implied_ at least that  Yashamaru took care of Gaara personally...until he tried to kill the kid. so it only stands to reason that _somebody_ would have had to do the same for Naruto, at least for the _first_ few years. Even given that the Third saw to his financial needs and housing, who was it that literally **took care** of the boy?

Answer (score 3):

We've seen that the concept of orphanages and adoption exists in the Ninja world. Case in point **Kabuto** who we know grew up in Konoha's Orphanage.

For further reading, http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konoha_Orphanage

So in my opinion, though not supported by any canon information, it is reasonable to assume baby Naruto would've been taken cared of in the orphanage. Unknown to him, he was guarded by Anbu from direct orders of third Hokage who kept a personal eye on him.

We know for sure that once he was big enough he started living alone. Since I am speculating I'll go further and say this can also be because the adults in Konoha hated Naruto and no one was ready to adopt him as their own.

Answer (score -1):

He probably had a caretaker to take care of him. But she probably got irritated at his energy and left when the series started. Thus the we see Naruto has no caretakers. The third and Iruka did  watch him and gave him money as we see in episode 350, the third says to Naruto:"here is this months fee."

Comment: Unless you have some sources to back up this statement, this answer is to speculative.

Comment: Nice reference. Still would be nice to know about much younger ages.